# Mimic Panning Behavior (velocity) of Photos App

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of the photos app where the user pans a photo with their finger and it has some velocity. For reasons I won't get into, I can't use a `UIScrollView` with its zooming `UIImageView` and instead have to implement a `UIImageView` with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Does Apple have any samples on how to do this, or does anyone know how to mimic the behavior? Any WWDC videos on this? (couldn't find any).

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to integrate any other third party ready made control than I would suggest you to have a look at [KTPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser) demo.

Its awesome. Everything is done programatically but you can change it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and hook the following function as selector to it.

```
-(void)scale:(id)sender {
  if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    lastScale = 1.0;
    CGSize zoomViewSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(imgScrollView.frame.size, [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender view].transform);
    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(imgScrollView.frame.origin, [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender view].transform);

    CGRect r = imgScrollView.bounds;
    CGSize scrollViewSize = imgScrollView.frame.size;
    imgScrollView.contentSize = zoomViewSize;
    imgScrollView.contentOffset = centerPoint; 
  }

  CGFloat currentScale = [[[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

  CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);
  scale = MIN(scale, imgScrollView.maximumZoomScale / currentScale);   
  scale = MAX(scale, imgScrollView.minimumZoomScale / currentScale);
  CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
  CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);
  [[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];
  lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, believe that is for scaling. Do you by chance know how to do it for panning?